# Determine If All Objects in Array Have a Matching Parameter

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects.

```
[
    {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },        {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },
    {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },
    {
      email: 'Johnny@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    }
]
```

How can I determine if all the objects property `email` match? Basically something like this.

```
if( all objects.email match ) {
     // they are all the same
} else {
    // They are not the same
}
```

Comment: `if all the objects property email match` match what? looks like you need [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 4):

[Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
var arr = [
    {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },        {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },
    {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },
    {
      email: 'Johnny@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    }
];

if (arr.every(item => item.email === 'john@example.com')) {
   // all match
}
```

If you are needing to see if more than 1 exists in the collection, it's a bit more complex. Using the same `arr` as above:

```
const dict = {};
arr.forEach(item => {
  if (!dict[item.email]) dict[item.email] = 0;
  dict[item.email]++;
});
Object.keys(dict).forEach(email => {
  if (dict[email] > 1) {
    console.log(`There are more than 1 ${email}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array.prototype.every` like Jaromonda said, you can do it this way :

```
const arr = [
    {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },        {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },
    {
      email: 'john@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    },
    {
      email: 'Johnny@example.com',
      name: 'John Doe'
    }
]

//if the array is empty, then we consider it as matching
//make the function independent from the Array's name
if(!arr[0] || arr.every( (entry, i, array) => entry.email === array[0].email ){
  //do your stuff here
}else{
  //do your stuff here
}
```